# Can you fail checks made to escape a grapple while under the effects of Freedom of Movement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, grapple

Freedom of Movement:

> The subject automatically succeeds on any combat maneuver checks and Escape Artist checks made to escape a grapple or a pin.

Does this mean that you are not required to roll a die? And if you are required to roll, and you roll a 1, do you fail?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. The spell *freedom of movement* is a difficult one to adjudicate. Thanks for the question and your participation.

Comment: Incidentally, skills don't automatically succeed on a 20, nor do they automatically fail on a 1; those are special properties of attacks and saves.

Answer (score 5):

#### A creature breaks a [grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) if the creature's affected by a [*freedom of movement*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-of-movement) effect *and* the creature wants to break the grapple by making *either* a combat maneuver check *or* an [Escape Artist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/escape-artist) skill check...

The affected creature simply beats the foe's grapple check result (hence *automatically*), loosing itself from the foe's clutches. No roll is made.

#### ...But, were the creature somehow *forced* to roll, the creature would *probably* fail to break the grapple on a natural 1 *if* the creature were attempting to break the grapple by making a combat maneuver check

The section [Combat Maneuver Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Defense) on Determining Success says that

> Rolling a natural 20 while attempting a combat maneuver is always a success (except when attempting to escape from bonds), while rolling a natural 1 is always a failure.

Further, the section [Grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) on If You Are Grappled says that

> If you are grappled, you can attempt to break the grapple as a standard action by making a **combat maneuver check** (DC equal to your opponent's CMD; this does not provoke an attack of opportunity) or Escape Artist check (with a DC equal to your opponent's CMD). If you succeed, you break the grapple and can act normally.

Emphasis mine. An argument can be made that the grappled creature isn't *attempting a combat maneuver* and, instead, *making a combat maneuver check*, but I think many would agree that, given the above text, a natural 1 on an attempt to break a grapple by making a combat maneuver check probably *should* automatically fail. Ask the DM.

Either way, automatic failure isn't an issue were a creature instead to make an Escape Artist skill check to break a grapple. Skill checks—including this one—have no special effects on a natural 1 unless specifically mentioned (cf. the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device)).